# Override services injected in directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Just to be more precise, I am not trying to do that in a testing context.

With the `$controller` service it's possible to istantiate a controller, providing custom injected services to it, like:

```
var controllerImpl = ['$stateParams', function($stateParams) {
    console.log($stateParams)
}];

$controller(controllerImpl, {
    $stateParams: {foo: 'bar'}
})
```

In that case, the `controllerImpl` will read $stateParams as `{foo: 'bar'}` `$stateParams` service.

I would like to do the same with a directive, using `$compile` service (maybe), but I don't find any way to pass locals to that service.

Comment: Please provide your use case as it's not exactly clear what you want to achieve. `$controller` instantiates a controller, something you'd not do yourself. You wouldn't instantiate a directive yourself either.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`$injector`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector) directly to instantiate objects, but I'm not 100% sure how you plan to use it.

Both `invoke` and `instantiate` allow you to override services by providing a `locals` object.

```
function myService(dep1, dep2){ ... }

$injector.invoke(
  myService,
  this, //optional 'this' param
  {
     dep1: someCustomDependency 
  }
);

//instantiate assumes this is a
// constructor function
$injector.instantiate(
  myService,
  {
     dep1: someCustomDependency 
  }
);
```

You could theoretically create a new instance of a directive, with this technique, and then manually call it's linking function with an element and a new scope, but this seems like a bad idea.